# A Finite Element Method for a first order PDE?

Tags: finite-element, hyperbolic-pde, galerkin

I want to develop a finite element method to solve for $u(x,t)$ the PDE:
$$u_t+c u_x= \frac{-c}{x}u$$
where $c$ is a constant.

- so I am trying the following ( as Rothe's method? ) :

Letting $k= t_n- t_{n-1}$ ( we begin by time discretization? ) we can write
$$\frac{u_i^n-u_i^{n-1}}{k}+ c\left(\frac{u_i^n-u_{i-1}^{n}}{\Delta x}\right)=\frac{-c}{x}u_i^n$$
Which gives the time stepping formula $$\left(1+ \frac{kc}{x}+ \frac{kc}{\Delta x}\right)u_i^n= u_i^{n-1}+ \frac{kc}{\Delta x}u_{i-1}^{n}$$
I can't avoid to notice that this is a direct finite difference scheme, which can be implemented without using finite elements.

- How should I try the weak formulation of the PDE? I need help with that
  $$\int_\Omega u_t\phi(x) dx +c \int_\Omega u_x\phi(x) dx= \int_\Omega \frac{-c}{x}u\phi(x) dx$$
  $$\int_\Omega u_t\phi(x) dx +cu\phi(x)- c\int_\Omega u\phi'(x) dx= \int_\Omega \frac{-c}{x}u\phi(x) dx$$
  How to handle the time derivative of $u$ ?

Comment: Is $x=0$ part of your domain? What happens there?

Comment: The domain for $x$ should be $[0,\infty)$ but now I think we can just take $[1,\infty)$ to avoid $0$

Comment: What is the difference between this and [your previous question](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/41506/9667)?