# Numerical methods for $u_t+c u_x= \frac{-c}{x}u$?

Tags: finite-element, pde, numerics, hyperbolic-pde

I am looking for possible numerical methods to solve the PDE
$$u_t+c u_x= \frac{-c}{x}u$$

I am particularly interested in a Finite elements method, although I am also curious if you can expose some other methods.

Comment: It looks like there is an analytic solution here, if that's of interest.

Comment: Specifically, you can use the method of characteristics I assume. But you need to state the domain of possible $x$ values, and what you want to happen at $x=0$.